# Question on the generating series of Lucas Numbers

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series

I was reading the Wikipedia page on Lucas Numbers, but I didn´t understand something concerning the generating series.
[image]

How is $\phi(x)$ arranged from $2+x+x(\phi(x)-2) +x^{2}\phi(x)$ to $\frac{2-x}{1-x-x^{2}}$?

Comment: That is just solving tbe equation $\phi = 2 + x + x (\phi - 2) + x^2 \phi$ for $\phi$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with
$$\Phi(x)=2+x+x(\Phi(x)-2)+x^2\Phi(x)$$
First step: expand the parenthesis.
$$\Phi(x)=2+x+x\Phi(x)-2x+x^2\Phi(x)$$
Next step: compute $x-2x=-x$.
$$\Phi(x)=2-x+x\Phi(x)+x^2\Phi(x)$$
Next step: move everything containing $\Phi(x)$ to the left side:
$$\Phi(x)-x\Phi(x)-x^2\Phi(x)=2-x$$
Next step: factor out the common $\Phi(x)$ from both sides:
$$\Phi(x)(1-x-x^2)=2-x$$
Final step: divide both sides by $1-x-x^2$:
$$\Phi(x)=\frac{2-x}{1-x-x^2}$$
Done.

Comment: Nice to get points for such a straightforward answer.